# Override bootstrap version in Angular component

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm using Angular 7 and using the [ngx-admin](https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin) template, which uses Bootstrap 4.

But I have a component which I need to use bootstrap 3 (yes I really do). How can I override the bootstrap/global styles for a specific component in Angular? I have tried using the different options of `ViewEncapsulation` but that hasn't really worked for me.

I thought I could maybe ignore the global styles in my component (somehow) and reference bootstrap 3 in my component html but that hasn't worked:

Html file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<p>This is the component I want to use bootstrap 3 in</p>>
```